# Azure App Services and SSL Certificate

Tags: azure, ssl, ssl-certificate

Can someone clear up the whole SSL certificate thingy on Azure, please?

I thought I needed to create a CSR *on the hosting server* to get an SSL certificate?

But if I am hosting on Azure App Services, how can this be?

I can see you can buy an SSL certificate through Azure itself but it is like twice as expensive as from a third party vendor.

But, I also see you can import an SSL certificate.  So does this mean I *dont* need to create a CSR on the hosting server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I needed to create a CSR on the hosting server

The CSR can be generated on any machine.

Build the `.pfx` bundle (with your private key) once you have the public part of your certificate from your preferred vendor and import to Azure.

OpenSSL example —

```bash
openssl pkcs12 -export \
               -out certificate.pfx \
               -inkey privateKey.key \
               -in publicCertFromVendor.crt \
               -certfile more.crt
```

`more.crt`: Optional, this is if you have any additional certificates you would like to include in the PFX file, like intermediates.

Comment: so just to confirm, I *can* create the CSR on any machine?  Vendors have said and everywhere I read suggests I should generate the CSR on the hosting machine, which didn't really make any sense to me.
It appears you are saying what I am thinking, I can generate it anywhere and then upload to Azure.
Thanks.

Comment: That's correct, anywhere. Just make sure you don't accidentally leave your private key behind.

Answer (score 0):

From Kudu or an Azure comand line you can run either OpenSSL or certreq to create whatever certs you want.